# fast free BI DB

Tags: performance

I'm looking for a good DB to run aggregations on. I need to run queries of style:

```
SELECT p.Product_Category, c.Country, SUM(f.sales)
FROM facts f
JOIN Customer c on f.ckey = c.ckey
JOIN Product p on f.pkey = p.pkey
GROUP BY p.Product_Category, c.Country
```

and get results fast.

I did a little benchmarking with this data: facts ~420,000 rows, product ~600 rows, customer ~360,000 rows. the aggregation gets back 6 countries and 4 product-categories (24 rows).

with SqlServer i'm getting about 250ms.

i've tried:

1. MonetDB - about the same time
2. Apache Drill - direct connection to SqlServer - about 2.5 sec.
3. Apache Drill - from parquet files - about 500ms.
4. Raima DB - about 12 sec. (only for the product, got out of memory for when adding customer)
5. MySql about 3sec.

and so on...

I know that MS tabular can get this result in about 15ms. And I saw another half baked engine (it wasn't done and ready to use) that gone about 100ms on first run and 5ms on second run. these are the kind of times I'm looking for!

If I could connect to it from java it would be great!

Is there a good solution for my needs?

PS there are only PK, not FK and no additional indexing. The schema design isn't up for changes (mainly because I won't know what it head of time).

Thanks!

Comment: Try columns tore and inmemory technology in sql server .. see how much of gain it offers.

Comment: @Kin I'm hoping to leave SqlServer and move to to open source non-windows techology. If nothing works, I'll try to look into SqlServer again.

Comment: @Peter I what to run a general purpose BI system. mostly it includes joining and aggregating like the example query (99% of the queries look like that). It's basically like running MDX through ROLAP, just skipping the cube and going straight to the sql.

Comment: Have you ever heard the phrase: "there is no such thing as a free lunch"? ;)

Answer (score 1):

All relational dbs should be "good at aggregations". Thats what they're designed for. Most db's follow similar design rules. To produce your result,  they all have to do the same math.

Im not familiar with other products but to consistently achieve response times like that you'll need to have the data in memory already (cached) and/or pre-calulated. Either using an aggregate table or an OLAP cube.

The first time your query runs will be the slowest. If you can reuse the same query it will be faster. The more you can reuse the same query - the faster *on average* it will be. If you can pre-execute the query ahead of time your client may never experience the delay.

Re-use and cacheing depend upon how often the data changes and how often the same query is executed.

If the underlying data or the query changes, you go through the over head of calculating the execution plan and io again.

If the data changes how quickly do you need the aggregate to reflect the change?

If you are developing a proof of concept sql developer edition has column store indexes and memory optimised table features which may help, but if this goes into production you'd need Enterprise edition which isnt free.

You could use an SSAS OLAP cube with SQL standard but there will be a lag while processing. However SQL Std isnt free either.

It may be possible to achieve this with SQL express and standard query tuning and/or aggregate tables. Frequently executing the query will assist with caching which will help performance. Stored procs and parameterisation will also help.

I doubt just picking a different product will magically make this query go faster without some other compromise. They all have to do the same math. They all have to write to and read from disk at some point.

Based upon the volumes you have described and the desire to use 'free' dbs i would consider sql express and aggregate tables updated periodically.

Comment: i could to an ETL process every now and then. I actually haven't looked at OLAP solutions. I know only MS-SSAS. are there any good MDX OLAP open source products out there?

Comment: So if you can accept updating periodically, you could perform your query and insert/update results to an aggregate table. And you could select from that. As your result set is so small querying that should be almost instantaneous.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure when you are querying parquet files through drill that those are in compressed with snappy algorithm. I had about 40M rows parquet file and for query like urs in Drill results were better than in ur case.

Have you tryed with Cassandra?
Or to query parquet file with spark?
Spark is fast and general engine for big data processing, with built-in modules for streaming, SQL ans etc and maybe he could help you.

Comment: I was using the default compression. and it seems to be snappy. an i re-checked, i used only the products with drill as well, and it's still slow. ~3sec first run. after a couple goes down to 0.5.

isn't cassandra NoSql? is that good for aggregating and joining data that's already relational? (i could migrate, but is it better than sql?)

I'll take a look at spark at let you know how it goes..
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are right, Cassandra is NoSQL.  But in Cassandra you are building tables for queries and than you have no more Joins adn group by. Every time you insert new row the same row will be partitioned ann group by the columns which are in "primary key" and primary key has partition and clustering keys ( I can explain it more if you want). Also, you can query Cassandra through Spark. Spark is pulling already orginized data from Cassandra and than you can query the same data on the say you want.